# monitor syslog and print line without `pattern`

Tags: bash, grep, tail, watch-command

I would like to monitor my `/var/log/syslog` continuously. However while monitoring, I would like to avoid certain pattern(s) while monitoring. I am interested only in the last 15 (for example) lines.

For the usual monitoring I use the command:

```
watch -n 1 tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog
```

Whereas, what I actually would like to have is something like:

```
watch -n 1 tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog | grep -v -E 'pattern1|pattern2'
```

Being more specific with my requirement:

I would like to continuously monitor entries in the `syslog`, avoiding certain pattern(s). The screen should get refreshed every fixed period (say 1s or 2s).

Following are more (failed) attempts:

```
watch cat /var/log/syslog | grep -v -E 'pattern1|pattern2'
```

A (partially) successful attempt:

```
while true;
do 
  clear;
  cat /var/log/syslog | grep -v -E 'pattern1|pattern2' | tail -15;
  sleep 1;
  echo '\"CTRL-C\" to close';
done
```

However the *smoothness* of `watch` is lost here.

**Summary**

So the question is is there any way to combine `watch`, `tail` and `grep`?

I am using `bash 4.4.7` on 17.04.

Comment: so, noob question from me - what's wrong with `tail -f`? That works with `grep`...

Comment: I need only last 15 lines to be displayed on the screen. This I can mange by `watch` clubbed with `tail`.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? my *guess* is you're not seeing what you expect because grep is buffering

Comment: `tail -f` will keep on priducing the output. The first line on the screen (till the screen fills up and starts scrolling) will always be the same. I would only last `n` lines displayed. In some sense, *forced scrolling*.

Comment: _A Dumb man's workaround_: Adjust the size of your window, so that only `n` lines fit and then use `tail -f`. Then you will achieve what you want! Adjusting size is (trivially) possible for a `gnome-terminal`. But its also possible for `screen/tmux` based terminals.

Comment: You might check out `glogg`. It can monitor syslog, or any log file, and give you control over search strings.

Comment: Try `watch -n 1 'tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog | grep -v -E "pattern1|pattern2"'` (the quoting is significant; you want the whole pipeline to run in the `watch` I think)

Comment: @heynnema, I will have a look at `glogg`.

Comment: @steeldriver, great! It works... So quotes at the appropriate places was the only thing I was missing! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your `watch -n 1 tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog | grep -v -E 'pattern1|pattern2'`, I *think*, is that it runs `tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog` inside `watch`, then pipes the result to `grep`. That almost certainly causes the intermediate output to be buffered in such a way that you don't see what you expect (at least, not when you expect it).

There's probably a way to achieve what you want with clever use of `stdbuf` and/or the `--line-buffered` grep option, however a simpler way is to run the whole pipeline inside `watch`:

```
watch -n 1 'tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog | grep -v -E "pattern1|pattern2"'
```

Comment: It works! Unfortunately its not suiting my needs. I will open another thread for that! Thanks anyways...

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/q/930342/698199) is my actual problem.