# `watch`, `tail`, `grep` combination in `byobu`'s `windows.tmux`

Tags: grep, byobu, tmux, gnu-screen, watch-command

I am (re)writing my `windows.tmux` for my frequently used `byobu` sessions. Below is my precise requirement:

I would like to have a tab (or window?) with a root prompt. (On start, it waits for the sudo passwd). I would like the second one to be split horizontally. In the upper portion I want to monitor my `/var/log/syslog` and in the lower one `dmesg`. So far I am able to achieve by doing the following:

```
new-session -AD -s 'root' sudo su - ;
new-window -n log watch -n 1 tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog
split-window watch dmesg | tail -15;
```

However the problem (which is completely irrelevant to this thread) that there are lots of entries in my `syslog` (almost 4/5 lines per second), which I would like to avoid while monitoring. So I would like to `grep -v` on these lines. The combination of `watch`, `tail` and `grep` can be achieved as per my need (thanks to [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) for his answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/929952/698199).)

```
watch -n 1 'tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog | grep -v -E "pattern1|pattern2"'
```

Here begins the problem: If I include the following line in my `window.tmux`

```
new-window -n log watch -n 1 'tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog | grep -v -E "pattern1|pattern2"'
```

I get,

```
sh: 1: tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog | grep -v -E "pattern1|pattern2": not found
```

In fact the more general problem is if I encapsulate the command in quotes (whether single `'` or double `"`), I get the same error.

Output of `byobu --version` is:

```
byobu version 5.116
tmux 2.3
```

I am using `GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release` on 17.04.

Thanks in advance
-- Mike

I have not experimented with `screen`. Is this *achievable* using `screen`?

Comment: Looks like this is a problem with parsing of `windows.tmux`. The `new-window` (same with `new-session`, `split-window`) command(s) of `tmux` cannot escape the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `bashrc` create an alias

```
alias monitor_log='tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog | grep -v -E "pattern1|pattern1"'
```

Your `windows.tmux` can be:

```
new-session -AD -s 'root' sudo su - ;
new-window -n log;
split-window watch dmesg | tail -15;
```

This will give you a bash-prompt in the second window-top split and dmesg in the bottom. And then give your favourite `watch` command:

```
watch -n 1 'tail -n 15 /var/log/syslog | grep -v -E "pattern1|pattern2"'
```

Not sure you can create an alias for this!

Hope this helps.